# Linq to SQL storage attribute issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an application that gets and stores data to a database using Linq to SQL.  I have a field for a phone number.  I am trying to store this consistently as only digits and nothing else.  To do this, I have two extension methods I've added to strings.  `ToPhoneFormat()` formats the phone digits as the user wants such as "(xxx) xxx-xxxx" or "xxx.xxx.xxxx".  `ToPhoneStorage()` removes all formatting and only saves the digits from the number for use with the database.

Here's a sample of code used with the Linq to SQL:

```
private string homePhone;
  [Column(CanBeNull = true, DbType = "nvarchar(25)", Name = "HOME_PHONE_NUM", Storage = "homePhone")]
  [Display(Name = "Home Phone")]
  public string HomePhone {
     get { return homePhone.ToPhoneFormat(); }
     set { homePhone = value.ToPhoneStorage(); }
  }
```

When I submit changes using the DataContext, Linq does in fact call the getter here, and the formatted phone gets sent back to the database.  Am I not understanding the `Storage` attribute properly?  Seems like it should work correctly like this.

Of course I can create two fields "PhoneDigits" and "PhoneFormatted" and only provide the column atribute to the "Phone" field. So I know there's a work around.  But what does the `Storage` attribute do if it doesn't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColumnAttribute`'s `Storage` property tells Linq-to_Sql to use the private field `homePhone` to get and set values of the property. So the actual getter and setter are bypassed.

You could remove the `Storage` property assignment. The code doesn't look like a part of a generated dbml, so this won't get overwritten. On the other hand I don't think linq-to-sql will be able to track changes to the property without the regular plumbing code in the setter (`SendPropertyChanged` etc.). And if you add this code manually it will also be triggered when the object gets materialized from the database, so it will always start its life in a modified state. (That's what's prevented by setting the private member). A rock and a hard place...

Comment: I decided to create two properties - HomePhone and HomePhoneFormatted.  The HomePhone maps directly to the database field. The HomePhoneFormatted gets and sets the HomePhone field but either applies formatting or removes it, and does not correlate to the database. Then I ran SQL commands on the database to unformat the existing data. Thanks for the info.